# Why doesn't my installed (on Windows in a virtual environment) python script work without a full path?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, package, virtualenv

I wrote a small python package and then installed it in my Python 2.7 virtual environment using pip. My package includes a command-line utility script, let's call it `my_script.py` that uses functionality from my package via an `import mypkg` call. The script is successfully installed into my virtualenv Scripts folder, but after activating my virtualenv, if I call

`(my_env) > python my_script.py --help`

I get the error:

`python: can't open file 'my_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

and if I call

`(my_env) > my_script.py --help`

I get the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyEnvs\my_env\Scripts\my_script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mypkg
ImportError: No module named mypkg`

(even though `mypkg` clearly shows up in the `pip list`). Only if I call

`python C:\PyEnvs\my_env\Scripts\my_script.py --help`

does the script work as expected. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a deficiency of virtualenv on Windows?

(Further note that `C:\PyEnvs\my_env\Scripts` is in my %PATH%, and I get the same behavior even if `C:\PyEnvs\my_env\Scripts` is also in my %PYTHONPATH%.)

Comment: [This discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/707281-search-path-python-script) is similar, but does not resolve as nicely as I would like. Why doesn't python use either PATH or PYTHONPATH when locating the scripts it is going to run?!

Answer (score 0):

```
> python my_script.py
```

will only work if the current directory is in your PATH environment variable.  If it is not, you must specify the directory it is un, either completely, or relative to your working directory.

so you could do:

```
> python .\myscript.py
```

or update your PATH and add "." for current directory.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: my_script.py is already in PATH. The virtualenv activation process adds C:\PyEnvs\my_env\Scripts to PATH, and that is where my_script.py is.